# Minor interface bugs when creating a question (help panes)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, reference

Make sure you are using IE7 and screen resolution of 1024x768, so that the page fits horizontally but doesn't fit vertically.

Go to the Ask Question page.

- The pages loads and the cursor is in the Title box. The `How To Ask` pane appears to the right.
  Scroll the page down so that the pane is forced to move down, following the top border of the window. As soon as the border hits the pane, the pane forgets about its own right border and partially goes beyond the screen.
  As soon as you scroll back up, so that the pane takes its original place, the right border of the pane is respected again.
- Move the cursor to the question body box. The `How To Format` pane appears.
  Scroll the page down again. As soon as the window hits the pane, the pane moves down properly, but when you scroll back up, the pane disappears as soon as it reaches its original position. It will not display again until you scroll the page down again.
- Move the cursor to the Tags box. The `How To Tag` pane appears.
  Now try scrolling the page, and both of the two effects will show up: the pane will forget about its own right border when forced to move down following the window, and will disappear when you scroll the page back up.
- Now move the cursor back to the Title box. The `How To Ask` pane appears again.
  Do some scrolling. This time, unlike the first time, the pane will both forget about its right border and disappear as soons as it goes back to its original place.

  - Try loading the page anew. You'll notice the `How To Ask` is not disappearing any more when you scroll the page, but it will start disappearing as soon as you leave the Title field and then activate it again.

Comment: Repro-ed all of these w/IE7 on WinXP.  Did not repro any of these with IE6 on WinXP, but IE6 had numerous other issues to be described in a later post.  Page works fine in Chrome 5.0, FF2 and FF3 (still on WinXP).  The boxes do disappear behind the "You've earned X and n other badges" bar.  I know that's not a bug; just reporting for completeness.

Comment: @badp, you must have lots of time on your hands...

Comment: @Popular, whoy do you have so many browsers available?  @badp, you too?

Comment: @Justin, I've just been silently suffering this bug for quite a long time; I use both Chromium dailies on Linux and Chrome Dev Channel on Windows. I didn't report it because explaining it isn't simple.

Comment: @Justin, I was doing frontend work a while ago and had to check things' appearances in several browsers.  Never bothered uninstalling them.

Comment: Whoops, I'm actually reproing another issue. Well, the behaviour of those boxes is still quite erratical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was from using style `position:fixed` while not having an explicit width set on the element.  The width is now set via script on page load.

The fix will be pushed out to all sites this evening.

Comment: I've pushed the fix here to meta SO - let me know if there's still some issue!

Comment: The reported issues are fixed as far as I can see.  Minor nitpick: the box appears a few pixels too high on initial page load, but that resolves after scrolling down and back up.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows XP, IE 8, and 1152x864 I was unable to reproduce the issues with the how to format box. However the How to tag and the Reference box did this:
[alt text http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/7010/scrollissue.png](http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/7010/scrollissue.png)
[alt text http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/7759/tagscrollissue.png](http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/7759/tagscrollissue.png)

I think a better question is why the box needs to resize itself when the user is scrolling down. In Google Chrome (Windows and Linux) the box resizes when I scroll down.

EDIT:
IE8 Compatibility view, scrolled down
[alt text http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/5950/ie8compatview.png](http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/5950/ie8compatview.png)

IE8 Compatibility View try #2:
[alt text http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/5121/ie8compatviewnothing.png](http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/5121/ie8compatviewnothing.png)

Comment: I think "minor" is an understatement. For our poor IE users who don't know any of the formatting rules, this makes the Ask Question page a bit unusuable